# GraphQL is not self documenting

Tags: php, graphql, self-documenting

I've created a GraphQL API for a project I'm working on using webonyx/graphql-php. I'm using Altair Chrome Plugin to test it. The API itself works fine, I can get the data without a problem, however Altair does not display any kind of documentation for the API. When I hit the reload button I can see in the network tab that Altair requests an IntrospectionQuery and my server does indeed reply with a big JSON file, however, no documentation appears in Altair. Since I do have documentation when using other GraphQL APIs I'm pretty sure the problem is on my side, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Find the JSON (reduced due to size limit) enclosed:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "message": 0,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "__schema": {
        "queryType": {
          "name": "Query"
        },
        "mutationType": null,
        "subscriptionType": null,
        "types": [
          {
            "kind": "OBJECT",
            "name": "Query",
            "description": "Base Query Object",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "senders",
                "description": "A list of senders",
                "args": [
                  {
                    "name": "offset",
                    "description": "Offset from where to look",
                    "type": {
                      "kind": "SCALAR",
                      "name": "Int",
                      "ofType": null
                    },
                    "defaultValue": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "limit",
                    "description": "Limit the number of senders (max 50)",
                    "type": {
                      "kind": "SCALAR",
                      "name": "Int",
                      "ofType": null
                    },
                    "defaultValue": "50"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "fsk",
                    "description": "Agerating (either 12 or 16)",
                    "type": {
                      "kind": "SCALAR",
                      "name": "Int",
                      "ofType": null
                    },
                    "defaultValue": "16"
                  }
                ],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "LIST",
                  "name": null,
                  "ofType": {
                    "kind": "OBJECT",
                    "name": "sender",
                    "ofType": null
                  }
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "sender",
                "description": "A single sender by ID or Name",
                "args": [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "description": null,
                    "type": {
                      "kind": "SCALAR",
                      "name": "Int",
                      "ofType": null
                    },
                    "defaultValue": null
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "name",
                    "description": "Get a sender by name",
                    "type": {
                      "kind": "SCALAR",
                      "name": "String",
                      "ofType": null
                    },
                    "defaultValue": null
                  }
                ],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "OBJECT",
                  "name": "sender",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              }
            ],
            "inputFields": null,
            "interfaces": [],
            "enumValues": null,
            "possibleTypes": null
          },
          {
            "kind": "OBJECT",
            "name": "sender",
            "description": "A single sender",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "id",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "name",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "sexuality",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "country",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "sexualPreferences",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "LIST",
                  "name": null,
                  "ofType": {
                    "kind": "SCALAR",
                    "name": "String",
                    "ofType": null
                  }
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "age",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "status",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "score",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "ddi",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "slogan",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "zip",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "relationship",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "occupation",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "height",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "hairLength",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "hairColor",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "languages",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "LIST",
                  "name": null,
                  "ofType": {
                    "kind": "SCALAR",
                    "name": "String",
                    "ofType": null
                  }
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "gender",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "figure",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "breastSize",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "description",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "preview12",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "OBJECT",
                  "name": "Image",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "preview16",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "OBJECT",
                  "name": "Image",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "images",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "LIST",
                  "name": null,
                  "ofType": {
                    "kind": "OBJECT",
                    "name": "Image",
                    "ofType": null
                  }
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              }
            ],
            "inputFields": null,
            "interfaces": [],
            "enumValues": null,
            "possibleTypes": null
          },
          {
            "kind": "OBJECT",
            "name": "Image",
            "description": "A sender image",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "id",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "fsk",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Int",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "type",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              },
              {
                "name": "urls",
                "description": null,
                "args": [],
                "type": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "SourceSet",
                  "ofType": null
                },
                "isDeprecated": false,
                "deprecationReason": null
              }
            ],
            "inputFields": null,
            "interfaces": [],
            "enumValues": null,
            "possibleTypes": null
          },
          {
            "kind": "SCALAR",
            "name": "SourceSet",
            "description": null,
            "fields": null,
            "inputFields": null,
            "interfaces": null,
            "enumValues": null,
            "possibleTypes": null
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I was building schema introspection for my PureScript GraphQL implementation, I was using GraphQL Playground. Playground let's you open the devtools and I would usually see a JavaScript or GraphQL error there. Like "cannot read property x of null". Then I would know what field was missing. Maybe you could at least try it out with Playground and see if it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was annoyingly simple after much searching - my response Object wraps the data in wrapped JSON format, so it comes out as data->data->__schema, where it should be data->__schema.

Simply unwrapping it before the output solves the problem.